# Group by data to dataframe columns with pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, bigdata

I have the following DataFrame. Describe the cities where each user lived

```
       City     Name    Date
0   Seattle    Alice    2017
1   Seattle      Bob    2011
2  Portland  Mallory    2010
3   Seattle  Mallory    2016
4   Memphis      Bob    2012
5  Portland  Mallory    2013
```

Can you with pandas achieve the following?

```
     Name     City1    Date1   City2   Date2   City3    Date3
0   Alice     Seattle  2017    NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
1   Bob       Seattle  2011    Memphis 2012    NaN      NaN
2   Mallory   Portland 2010    Seattle 2016    Portland 2013
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with custom function where create new `DataFrame`, then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sort second level of `MultiIndex` by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last use `join` for remove it:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name')['City','Date']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values, 
                                      columns = ['City','Date'], 
                                      index = np.arange(1, len(x) + 1).astype(str)))
        .unstack()
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1, level=1).replace({None:np.nan})
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(''.join)
print (df1)
            City1  Date1    City2   Date2     City3   Date3
Name                                                       
Alice     Seattle   2017      NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
Bob       Seattle   2011  Memphis  2012.0       NaN     NaN
Mallory  Portland   2010  Seattle  2016.0  Portland  2013.0
```